# Bus error after mmap success

Tags: c, linux, mmap, file-mapping

**Context**

- Linux 4.4.0-57-generic #78-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 9 23:50:32 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- French locale

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main() {
   int fd = open( "/tmp/mapped.bin", O_CREAT|O_RDWR|O_SYNC, 0666 );
   perror("open");
   unsigned char * dst =
      (unsigned char *)mmap(
         NULL, 64*1024, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0 );
   perror("mmap");
   static unsigned char src[] = { 1, 3, 5, 7 };
   printf("memcpy( %p, {%d,%d,%d,%d}, %zd )\n", dst, src[0], src[1], src[2], src[3], sizeof(src));
   memcpy(dst, src, sizeof(src));
   perror("memcpy");
   return 0;
}
```

**Production**

```
$ gcc -W -Wall -std=c11 src/org/hpms/filemap/BusError.c -o bin/BusError
(no warning, no error)
```

**Execution**

```
$ bin/BusError
open: Success
mmap: Success
memcpy( 0x7f51291fe000, {1,3,5,7}, 4 )
Erreur du bus
```

**gdb**

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/aubin/Dev/Java/2017/org.hpms.filemap/bin/BusError
open: Success
mmap: Success
memcpy( 0x7ffff7fe6000, {1,3,5,7}, 4 )

Program received signal SIGBUS, Bus error.
0x00000000004005ac in main () at src/org/hpms/filemap/BusError.c:15
15     memcpy(dst, src, sizeof(src));
(gdb)
```

Comment: `typedef byte bytes_t` is missleading. Also note that POSIX reserves names ending with `_t`; you must not use them. If you need bytes, use `unsigned char` directly and don't `typedef` obscure aliases like that. If you want 8 bit types, use the fixed width type `uint8_t`. Said that: with almost 10k rep, you should know [ask] and to provide a [mcve]! What do the functions return? How about errors? ...

Answer (score 4):

You'll get SIGBUS if you access the mmaped memory outside the file. In other words, if you want to write 4 bytes, the file needs to be at least 4 bytes large.

In your example, you could solve the problem with `ftruncate`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
   int fd = open( "/tmp/mapped.bin", O_CREAT|O_RDWR|O_SYNC, 0666 );
   perror("open");
   unsigned char * dst =
      (unsigned char *)mmap(
         NULL, 64*1024, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0 );
   perror("mmap");
   static unsigned char src[] = { 1, 3, 5, 7 };
   ftruncate(fd, sizeof src);
   perror("ftruncate");
   printf("memcpy( %p, {%d,%d,%d,%d}, %zd )\n", dst, src[0], src[1], src[2], src[3], sizeof(src));
   memcpy(dst, src, sizeof(src));
   perror("memcpy");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You really should make the file size a multiple of 4K aka the page size, if you can. It simplifies all of the memory management.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72179836/can-the-os-automatically-grow-an-mmap-backed-file