# Can the OS automatically grow an mmap backed file?

Tags: linux, posix, mmap

`mmap` has many uses but I primarily use `mmap` in two ways:

- mmap to read an entire file
- mmap to create shared memory.

In the case of shared memory if I want it backed by a file I use `ftruncate()` to make sure the size of the file exactly matches the size of the region I wish to `mmap`.

I'm curious about what happens if the file sizes does not match.
The man page does not give sufficient detail here.

I think mmap has to handle this for the case of reading a file.
For example, because the length of a file does not have to be a multiple of the page size
and you might only want to read a portion of the file.

What about in the case of writing it?

Can the OS create the file backed storage lazily?

For example if I mmap 1Gb to an empty file.

Will the OS extend the file as necessary when I attempt to write to it?

My intuition (which is likely wrong) is that a mapping should behave consistently with file `read()` and `write()` calls.
So a read beyond the end of a file will fail
but a write beyond the end of a file will extend it as required.

In fact, I would also expect the page to be marked as dirty and only actually written to the physical file when `msync()` or `munmap()` is called. So the file only be extended at that point.

[This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249695/bus-error-after-mmap-success?rq=1) however suggest that a bus error would occur.

Is that always the case or is it true for some combinations of flags only?
What is going on under the hood here?

This is not something I'm trying to do but a hypothetical use case might be a userspace implementation of swap which grows on demand. For example, if you were trying to save disk space.

Another way of posing the question is:

Is it actually necessary to call `ftruncate()` before using `mmap()`?

I'm interested in Linux specifically but curious about POSIX correctness as well.

Comment: The other question is correct. You can't grow a file with `mmap()`, there's no options to get around this.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15684771/how-to-portably-extend-a-file-accessed-using-mmap?rq=1

Comment: @Barmar that would be the answer I'm looking for but with an explanation of what actually goes on under the hood so I can update my mental model.

Comment: Its also worth noting that [ftruncate can create a sparse file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33904633/1569204) so the space is not used until written. Contrast with fallocate() which ensures the disk space is reserved. This question is asking about growth on demand.

Comment: Under the hood is simple: virtual memory pages are only allocated for portions of the file that exist. If you try to access outside that, you get a fault.